# order of propery initializtion and propery dependency

Tags: javascript

In the below code the value of centerX is Not a Number(NAN). I am assuming that when the value for the property centerX is computed , the properties "x" and "width" are valid. It seems this is not the case. What is the order of property initialization.

```
var some_object = { x: 50,
                    width: 100,
                    centerX: this.x + this.width / 2 // This prints centerX as NAN
                  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a property of a [function execution context](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3) that depends on how the function gets called. In your case as there's no function, `this` will default to `window`, and those properties don't exist, this reads as:

```
undefined + undefined / 2 == NaN
```

You could create a getter:

```
var obj = {
  x: 50,
  width: 100,
  center: function(){
    return this.x + this.width / 2;
  }
};

obj.center(); // `this` is the receiver
```

Or, you can assign the property to the object after declaration:

```
var obj = {
  x: 50,
  width: 100
};

obj.center = obj.x + obj.width / 2;
```

It depends on how you want to use your object. The first one is portable, and you compute the properties at your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, when the value of centerX is computed, `this` does not represent the object  `some_object` as you would expect.

If you type your code in a browser console, `this` is the browser window.

Depending on where your statement is located in your code, `this` could be anything. This anything doesn't have either a property named `x`, either a property named `width` (or none of the two) :

```
this.x === undefined
```

or

```
this.width === undefined
```

So

```
this.x + this.width / 2 === NaN
```

Instead, you could create your object

```
var some_object = { 
  x: 50,
  width: 100
}
```

and add it a function

```
some_object.foo = function() { 
    // Here, 'this' exists and represents 'some_object'
    this.centerX = this.x + this.width / 2;
 }

// call the function
some_object.foo();
```

Then you would have the expected

```
some_object.centerX === 50
```